# Images shifting out of container after adding divs

Tags: html, css, overlay

So my website has 3 images which span across the full width, each using 33.33% width and a fixed height (800px). I would like to create a fade in overlay on each seperate image, however as soon as I being adding some divs to the html code 2 of the images get shifted down, even though i'm not adding any space. Any ideas?

[How it should behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcail.jpg)

[What happens upon adding new divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1d0S.jpg)

Here's the code without any new divs, any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<div id="content">
        <img src="images/phantom.png"alt="An image showing a male actor performing during the musical Phantom of the Opera" class="musicalimage">
        <img src="images/lion_king.png" alt="An image showing a male actor performing during the musical Lion King" class="musicalimage">
        <img src="images/wicked.png" alt="An image showing a female actor performing during the musical Wicked" class="musicalimage">   
</div>`
```

---

```
#content {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;

}

.musicalimage {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 800px;
    display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display: flex` to `#content`

```css
#content {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.musicalimage {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 800px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img src="images/phantom.png" alt="An image showing a male actor performing during the musical Phantom of the Opera" class="musicalimage">
  <img src="images/lion_king.png" alt="An image showing a male actor performing during the musical Lion King" class="musicalimage">
  <img src="images/wicked.png" alt="An image showing a female actor performing during the musical Wicked" class="musicalimage">
</div>`
```

Comment: Huh so that's all it was.. thank you so much :D ps. What does flex really do though? I thought inline-block would do the same thing..

Comment: Just google flexbox, you will easily find quite a lot of resources